# Returning View just before HttpResponse

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Before prompting user to download an excel file I want to render a View. The problem is that when I return the view where I call the HttpResponse action, like this:

```
@Html.Action("Download", "DownloadController")
```

what happens is that the user is prompted straight away and the html is not rendered, so after user has opened / saved the file that he was promted, the previous view remains visible.

Am I missing something obvious here? What is the best practice when one encounters the need to perform such action?

Comment: Open it in a new tab?  i.e `target="_blank"`

Comment: Redirect to the new View, then from the new view start the download via ajax